# Error when user agent sniffing to assign template

Tags: angular

I am trying to do assign a template based on user agent detection but whenever I compile my script, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' (isMobile) ? './home.component.mobile.html' : './home.component.html''
```

**mobile.ts**

```
const regex_mobile = new RegExp(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/, 'i');
export const isMobile = regex_mobile.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { isMobile } from '../../providers/mobile/mobile';

@Component({
  templateUrl: (isMobile) ? './page.component.mobile.html' : './page.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing your own, just use angulars Breakpoint observer, found in angular's cdk package

```
npm install @angular/cdk
```

---

```
import { Breakpoints, BreakpointState, BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';


export class HomeComponent {
    isMobile: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);

    constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
}
```

In your template, you can then check using the `async` pipe

```
<div *ngIf="(isMobile | async).matches"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible for me to swap out the `templateUrl`? rather than have everything on the same page?

Comment: Similar to this: https://medium.com/@thatisuday/create-separate-mobile-version-in-angular-4-4ba5d5d825ff. I'd like to keep the mobile and desktop templates separate if possible!

Comment: No, you'd never do that. Create a parent component instead, and show the child components depending on the result

Comment: Ok got it. It was possible in AngularJS but I guess Angular is a completely different beast. How would the parent -> child component look like?

Comment: Parent holds the breakpoint observer, its template like: `<mobile-view *ngIf="isMobile | async"></mobile-view><desktop-view *ngIf="! (isMobile | async)"><desktop-view>`... Or using a if else with templates @methuselah

Comment: Strangely enough. I've started getting the following error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of null` even when I use `matches`

Comment: Where exactly do you place the check? In your other question, you don't use brackets. Can you please post more code in the new Q? @methuselah